# Python Multiple Turtle Shapes

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to have multiple turtles for a game. turtle is the main character and monster is another turtle i've added. How to I add a shape to it. Heres the code:

```
import turtle
monster = turtle.Turtle()
monster.addshape('enemt.gif')

monster.shape('enemt.gif')
monster.goto(0, 0)
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alfie\Desktop\Tutorial Game\Tutorial Game.py", line 77, in <module>
    monster.addshape('enemt.gif')
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'addshape'
```

Comment: Does `addShape` work? Names are case-sensitive.

Comment: No it doesn't. Same error again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rereading the documentation, `addshape()` is listed as a method of turtle but the examples show it as a method of the screen, which works:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

screen.addshape('enemt.gif')

monster = turtle.Turtle('enemt.gif')

monster.goto(0, 0)

turtle.done()
```

Actually, `turtle.addshape('enemt.gif')` also works in this code.

All methods of the Turtle class are also available as top level functions that operate on the *default* (unnamed) turtle instance.  All methods of the Screen class are also available as top level functions that operate on the *default* (sole) screen instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, but I'll answer for anyone else with the problem :P

```
monster = turtle.Turtle()
monster.addshape('enemt.gif')

monster.goto(0, 0)
monster.shape('enemt.gif')
```

monster.addshape('enemt.gif') doesn't work because addshape is only for turtle, not multiple. Now if you use

```
turtle.addshape()
```

it  works! But you use `monster.shape()` sorry if I can't answer these questions, if anyone knows the actual reason that this works, edit this please :P